# High Voltage & Low Voltage PCB Design

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, digital-logic, low-voltage

I am trying to make a PCB that acts as a "Raspberry PI HAT" and allows me to connect the raspberry to different sensors. Specifically, I'm having difficulties in defining the design rules for the coexistence of high voltage and low voltage. In fact some components operate at 5V, other components at 3.3V and finally the relays will be driven via GPIO pins (3.3V and a MOSFET for 5V power supply) and will have COM & NA pins that accommodate a maximum current of 10A and 220V voltage.

Currently I have therefore made the following diagram on 2 layers with the following settings for 220V:

Track Width: 2mm
Clearance: 2mm

I wanted to ask if these settings are valid, and if so, if it is necessary to follow additional design rules

Thank you in advance for the help
[image: PCB]

Comment: You needed 3 mm clearance and 1.8 mm creepage last time I checked. Are your tracks covered by soldermask?

Comment: _Low voltage_ and _High voltage_ are actually formal engineering terms. "Low voltage" being anything in the range 50 - 1000VAC or 75 - 1500VDC. Everything above that is "high voltage". Please don't make up own your meaning to established terms. The tags you picked even have descriptions telling you what they are for.

Comment: First of all thank to Lundin for the explaination about low-high voltages, so all the circuit is in Low voltage since it's range is 3.3V in DC and 220V in AC. I'll edit the tags.

Comment: Other than that, yes, the tracks are covered by the soldermask.
So it's not a problem to mix 220V AC with 3.3V-5V DC?

Comment: I’d avoid having mains traverse the pcb. Keep the mains at one end of the pcb. I’d also choose relays that have better creepage distance like the G2R series. Unfortunately your current design isn’t really viable. Signals from the outside world with no protection, power and gnd reference tracks way too thin. The list goes on. Use an Arduino for the data acquisition and control and let the raspi handle the upper level control.

Comment: Kartman thank you for the suggestions, at this moment the track width is 0.254mm, how thick should it be?

Comment: As thick as you can make it. Tracks have resistance and inductance. You want to minimize these. You also need to anticipate where the current is going to flow - separate the high current paths from the low current ones.

Comment: Sparking relays this close to a low voltage cortex cpu are also not a very wise idea. I'd recommend using low/high side mosfets or smart switches to switch low voltage 24V relays outside of the rpi area.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, thanks to all the answers i'm rethinking the structure of the pcb. Since I need to use this sparkling relay, I would ask how far should it be to prevent issues? At this moment it is few centimeters away from the raspberry pi (approximately 3 to 5 cm)